# Unity: Climb Ladder

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've been working in Unity on a first person game, and came across a feature I want to add: climbing ladders. However, I have been unsuccessful in coding this so far(btw I'm using javascript). Below is a script I have to test a collision with the ladder, which doesn't work:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(collider:Collision){
    if(collider.gameObject.name=="ladder"){
        Debug.Log("hit ladder");
    }
}
```

Technically, this should show the debug message "hit ladder" on collision with the ladder... but it doesn't.

Does anyone know why this isn't working, or how I could fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but C# is so much better for Unity.

Comment: yeah, so i've heard. do you know how i could do this in c#? actually, I feel like it's not the code... like something is set up wrong. but im not sure

Comment: Technically, it's UnityScript, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little late to the party, but here I go.

You could always make a trigger based ladder that applies an upward movement when the controller is moving forwards.

I have posted a blog entry explaining(With no code) how I went about implementing simple ladders in the old demo video that is also visible on the post.

http://www.lazr.pw/2014/02/unity-trigger-based-ladders.html

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Since this script is looking for a collision with a ladder, I'm assuming the script is within the character. If the script is within your ladder, well... there's the issue :P

In any case, if this is within your character, and you're probably using a CharacterController to move him, then `OnCollisionEnter` won't trigger. You need to use `OnControllerColliderHit(collider:Collision) { ... }` and put your collision detections within that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here that I can tell you.

1. Use [CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.OnControllerColliderHit.html) as Steven Mills has suggested, but take notice that the parameter being passed into the function is actually `ControllerColliderHit`.
2. Instead of checking the collider's name, compare the `Tag` of the `GameObject`. All you have to do is assign the same tag, let's say "Ladder", for each `GameObject` that you want to have this functionality.

Here's a C# example for you as well:

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit) {
    if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Ladder")) {
        //Climbing
    }
}
```

I would recommend looking at the link above for additional information. This is because you will probably want to perform additional checks like where the player is colliding with the ladder. This is because you may not want to be able to climb ladders from the ladder's sides (unless of course if the *ladder* is a *rope* or something similar). You will also need a way to tell that the player has finished climbing up/down the ladder. You probably don't want to still be climbing the ladder when your feet are above the top of it ;). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use OnTriggerEnter(Collider) instead (do not forget to set ladder as a trigger!)
2. Use Rigidbody (non-kinematic one) instead of Character Controller. Documentation says "Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached."